Using Vertical Photo Placer and Exiftool in Mac
I need help to make the Vertical Photo Placer plugin work, which needs Exiftool to work (to overlay open multiple georeferenced photos). The problem is that on Monteray 12.7 you can't find the Path to indicate to QGIS, that is, it's not where it should be (/usr/local/bin)...so this error message arrives...

Did you try adding the following line to your ~/.profile settings using a text editor:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin


Thak for your help, I add "ExifTool_config" in the same folder of exiftool, but seems not to work..

it seem not to be possible to find ~/.profile in my mac.. Monterey version 12.7.6

Command + Shift + . (period) to find hidden files?

Grazie, si i file non sono nascoti ma ~/.profile non c'è. Ho letto che non sempre esiste di defoult ma che bisogna crearlo.....
